# XSLT - add new node between numbers and text between content text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible in xslt to add new node between numbers and text within content text.

as example :

```
<doc>
  <a>1 Available accessibility features for....</a>
  <b>..between two teams of 11 players each on a..</b>
  <c>The game is played by 120 million players..</c>
</doc>
```

I need to add `<s>` node between numbers and text between above xml. so the output xml should be

```
<doc>
  <a>1<s/> Available accessibility features for....</a>
  <b>..between two teams of<s/> 11<s/> players each on a..</b>
  <c>The game is played by <s/>120<s/> million  players..</c>
</doc>
```

I tried hard find any method how can do this task but unable find any good solution. is there any possible way of do this in xslt ?

Comment: How do you define "numbers" here? It's clearly more than just sequences of digits, since you included the word "million", but you've not marked the word "two".

Comment: If you can write a regular expression to describe what you want to match then it should be easy enough using `analyze-string`, but if it's a more complex natural language task then another tool may be more appropriate than XSLT.

Comment: @IanRoberts , My bad. new node should add only between numbers and text. I have corrected the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Why is `of 11 players` transformed to `of<s/> 11<s/> players` (with a space before the number) while `by 120 million` is transformed to `by <s/>120<s/> million` (with no space before the number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplification of Martin's answer.  The way `analyze-string` works is to split the input string into a sequence of matching and non-matching substrings and use the appropriate handler for each.  Within a (non-)matching-substring handler, the `position()` function is the position of this substring within the list of substring chunks and `last()` is the total number of matching and non-matching substrings.  Thus you can use a much simpler regex that just matches the digits, and use `position()` to deal with the end effects:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]+">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1">
      <s/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() lt last()">
      <s/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

The first `if` is true if there was a non-matching substring before this matching substring, the second `if` is true if there is at least one non-matching substring still to go following the current matching one (while it's not necessarily the case in general, *for this particular regex* we can guarantee that matching and non-matching substrings will strictly alternate.  It's not possible to get two matching substrings next to each other with a greedy `+` quantifier).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This explains everything what I needed to know. :)

Answer (score 3):

As already suggested, this is a job for `analyze-string`. The stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="5">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^|[^0-9]+)([0-9]+)([^0-9]+|$)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(regex-group(1)) gt 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        <s/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(regex-group(3)) gt 0">
        <s/>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<doc>
  <a>1 Available accessibility features for....</a>
  <b>..between two teams of 11 players each on a..</b>
  <c>The game is played by 120 million players..</c>
</doc>
```

into

```
<doc>
  <a>1<s/> Available accessibility features for....</a>
  <b>..between two teams of <s/>11<s/> players each on a..</b>
  <c>The game is played by <s/>120<s/> million players..</c>
</doc>
```